# Using a function in R to scrape website, returning "subscript out of bounds" error

Tags: r, function, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape player data from the Baseball Reference website, using a function to loop through multiple years (variable "year") for each player notated by "playerid."

```
library(plyr)
library(XML)

fetch_stats <- function(playerid, year) {
  url <- paste0("http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.cgi?id=",playerid,"&t=b&year=",year)
  data <- readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  data <- data[[3]]
  data$Year <- year
  data$PlayerId <- playerid
  data
}
```

This function works perfectly well when it is applied to a single year's worth of data, as seen here:

```
AdrianGonzales <- ldply("gonzaad01", fetch_stats, year= 2008, .progress="text")
```

However, as soon as I actually use the function to loop through the multiple years in a players career, it always spits out the following error:

```
AdrianGonzales <- ldply("gonzaad01", fetch_stats, year= 2009:2004, .progress="text")

Error in data[[3]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
XML content does not seem to be XML: 'http://www.baseball-   reference.com/players/gl.cgi?id=gonzaad01&t=b&year=2009
http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.cgi?id=gonzaad01&t=b&year=2008
http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.cgi?id=gonzaad01&t=b&year=2007
http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.cgi?id=gonzaad01&t=b&year=2006
http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.cgi?id=gonzaad01&t=b&year=2005
http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.cgi?id=gonzaad01&t=b&year=2004'
```

From what I have been able to find, the "subscript out of bounds" error happens when you exceed the limits of a defined dataset within R.  For this particular function, I may just be dumb, but I don't see how that would apply in this case- or why it would work for a single year, but not for several at a time.

I'm open to any and all suggestions.  Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Could you add the `library` calls for `XML` and `plyr` to your question just for completeness.

Comment: Library calls added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `lapply` as in the following way below.  I put in a minor fix to `fetch_stats` as it seems that the 6th column returned has no name.  You can do what you like with it, as it is just to show how you can use `lapply` instead.

```
library(plyr)
library(XML)

# Minor change made to get function working (naming column 6)
fetch_stats <- function(playerid, year) {
  url <- paste0("http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.cgi?id=",playerid,"&t=b&year=",year)
  data <- readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  data <- data[[3]]
  data$Year <- year
  data$PlayerId <- played
  ### Column six name is empty.
  names(data)[6] <- 'EMPTY'
  data
}
res   <- lapply(2009:2004, function(x) fetch_stats("gonzaad01", x))
resdf <- ldply(res)
```

This will create a list of 6 elements, one for each year, then convert the list to a `data.frame`

The way `ldapply` is applied in your code, it is not giving it one year at a time, it is giving the entire vector of years all at once.

**EDIT**

After looking a little closer, here is a solution using `ldply`

```
new_res <- ldply(.data = 2009:2004,
                 .fun = function(x) fetch_stats("gonzaad01", x),
                 .progress="text")
```

This gave me the same results as the other method above.

Comment: This worked great, and I had no idea about the 6th column being empty.  Thanks so much!